# How to look for all active stamps in Agenda?

Tags: org-agenda

Sometimes I do not use SCHEDULE or DEADLINE, but a simple active date stamp.

With SCHEDULED items, they always show as pending, but not with active date stamps, as they are left behind if you don't mark them as DONE.

How could I retrieve all these "left behind" active stamped tasks?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the Org agenda dispatcher on `C-c a`, then `C-c a m TIMESTAMP<="<now>" RET` should show you all the left-behind timestamps, although I'm not sure it distinguishes actives from inactives. See [Matching tags and properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties) and [Special Properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties).

EDIT: The above finds active timestamps only. Finding both active and inactive timestamps is just a matter of OR'ing the searches:

```
C-c a m TIMESTAMP<="<now>"|TIMESTAMP_IA<="<now>"
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies! For some reason that does not show any left-behind active or inactive date stamps. I'm reading the links and coming back to it.

Comment: Does it show anything?

Comment: Yes, now it works! Thanks. However, it lists all active stamps in SCHEDULED DEADLINE, and both active and inactive timestamps. I was looking for only showing the active or inactive timestamps that are NOT SCHEDULE or DEADLINE items (because those show always in the agenda: SCHEDULE items always do until they are marked as DONE and deadlines always do too until marked also as DONE). I am looking for those tasks that are left behind forgotten. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: I think I mistyped: try it without the `/`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: Actually, this shows active but not inactive timestamps... any ideas?

Comment: Edited the answer